# Stopping Angular.js from running on pages in a specific directory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, .htaccess, google-crawlers

I am working on optimizing a angular site for SEO. Currently I have all the necessary static pages being scraped and created, the problem I'm seeing is that despite my .htaccess serving a static page up when hitting the corresponding url

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/snapshots/%1.html? [NC,L]
```

The whole process would go like this:

1.Google crawler hits mysite.com/#/home

2.Crawler see's that its a angular site (thanks to < meta name="fragment" content="!" > ) and re-crawls the page with the given url of mysite.com?_escaped_fragment_=home
 3. .htaccess sees this and redirects the crawler to mysite.com/snapshot/home.html which houses a static page with all the content. We now have a properly indexed page.

For those that aren't familiar with what I'm trying to do http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html

It looks as though Angular is still firing, as it continues to append a hashtag to the url (www.mysite.com?_escaped_fragment_=home/#/home). So how would I stop angular from adding to the url given that all static pages are living in a specific directory? 
  My original thoughts would be to just exclude my script include from the static pages, however that would become a tedious process if I work with large site. Is there a way to tell Angular to ignore firing/working if the file lives in a given directory?

edit:: Included some code and some more information.

Comment: Without reading your question in detail, why not use angular in HTML5 mode so that the path doesn't use a fragment?

Comment: Server isn't set up to handle html5 at this time. In the future I am likely to do so, but as for this given project it isn't a option.